# What is affected by DC/DC converter frequency selection?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, frequency, switching

I planning to use the [LMR33640](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmr33640.pdf) DC/DC converter which exists in 400kHz and 1MHz switching frequency versions. I know that the 1MHz version allows to use a smaller inductors. But I think that the 1MHz version has higher EMI emissions as a drawback (not sure)?

What other PROs and CONs do exist with switching converters concerning switching frequency selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The choice of frequency is usually constrained by 4 primary factors:

**1** Inductor size (as you mentioned). A higher frequency requires a smaller inductor with lower copper (\$I^2 R\$) losses as there are fewer windings for a smaller inductance with equivalent saturation current.

**2** Higher frequency operation increases switching losses in the switching FET. In synchronous buck converters we usually choose the switching FET for lowest total gate charge and the sync FET for lowest \$R_{DS(ON)}\$.

**3** Compensation. This *can* be a bit more challenging with a higher loop cutoff but is often worth it as the output error response time will be faster which can make ripple easier to deal with.

**4** Switch minimum on time; at higher frequencies this may be more difficult to meet the datasheet parameters. You can read an excellent [application note from TI](https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/powerhouse/archive/2017/01/12/how-to-overcome-minimum-on-time-challenges-in-switching-power-supplies) on this subject.

Those are the primary issues that require a compromise as they have competing interests. Whether there will be higher EMI or not is very device and layout dependent.

Comment: Very good answer. Thanks for the appnote link.

Answer (score 1):

You've pretty much got it.  The efficiency is usually better with lower switching frequencies as well.  Possibly the most important criterion is that, if possible, your switching frequency and its harmonics don't overlap with signals of interest.

Answer (score 1):

### Possibly an unrecognised “pro” (Generally)

If your primary emitted noise is caused by a high level of inductor peak to peak current, then running at a higher switching frequency allows a smoother level of CCM (or actually running in CCM from DCM) and, as a result, the peak to peak current will reduce for the same output power. This will of course reduce emitted noise but it isn’t necessarily a panacea to noise reduction generally in switching converters.

Comment: Excellent point; I have run into this where the output current has a very wide range requirement.